# None value pops up in python whenever i run this code

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import random

print("Dice Roll!")

while True:
    roll = random.choice (range (1, 7)) print(f" (roll) came up!")
    x = input(print("Roll dice again? (Y/N): ")).Lower()

    if x != "y":
        exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use {roll} insted (roll) in formated text

And dont use print inside input.
You have to pass just string.

```
import random
print("Dice Roll!")
while True:
    roll = random.choice (range (1, 7)) 
    print(f" {roll} came up!")
    x = input("Roll dice again? (Y/N): ").Lower()
    if x != "y":
        exit(0)
```